# dynamically create\remove textbox

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically create\remove textbox . I have a code. I have two file. One html file and other is java script file. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Adding and Removing Text Boxes Dynamically</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var intTextBox=0;
            //FUNCTION TO ADD TEXT BOX ELEMENT
            function addElement()
            {
                intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
                var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
                var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
                newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Text "+intTextBox+": <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "'    name='" + intTextBox + "'/>";
                contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
            }
            //FUNCTION TO REMOVE TEXT BOX ELEMENT
            function removeElement()
            {
                if(intTextBox != 0)
                {
                    var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
                    contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('strText'+intTextBox));
                    intTextBox = intTextBox-1;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Demo of Adding and Removing Text Box Dynamically using JavaScript</p>
        <p><a href="javascript:addElement();" >Add</a> <a href="javascript:removeElement();" >Remove</a></p>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to split this code so that I can write all function in javascript and I want to write this text box code `<input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "' name='" + intTextBox + "'/>";` in my html file so that I can use this textbox id to fetch value in compose email since it takes value from textbox id from html pages. Please help.

Comment: I recommend you to use a js library like jQuery: http://jquery.com/ this will be for sure a good choice to code more faster and for sure your code will do it's work on all major browsers

Comment: I am not clear. Which code do you want to split. You are already creating the text boxes where you can write.

Comment: I want to write these two function in java script file that I am importing in html file. And I want to add <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "' name='" + intTextBox + "'/>"; which is creating text box in html file. Right now all code is in one file.

Comment: @learner why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have to use this textbox id in my compose email file to fetch value from there and email file is taking value from html file.

Comment: Please refer to [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [link2](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/). Your question is not clear enough just like the other questions you have asked till now on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If all you're after is moving the code to a different file, then you basically pull the stuff from in-between script tags into a new file then update your script tag to:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="newfile.js">
/* stuff here was moved to the new file*/
</script>`

If you also want to make the function work for any textbox, then update the declaration to

```
function addElement(elementId)
```

and then use that instead of the hard-coded string when getting the element.

Comment: yes, but textbox is being created in add function as "newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Text "+intTextBox+": <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "'    name='" + intTextBox + "'/>";
contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);" and I want to write code to create text box in html file not in this function that will be in java script file .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your `script` from your `HTML` code, you can use the following snippet

```js
var intTextBox = 0;
//FUNCTION TO ADD TEXT BOX ELEMENT
function addElement() {
  intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
  var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
  var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newTBDiv.setAttribute('id', 'strText' + intTextBox);
  newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Text " + intTextBox + ": <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "'    name='" + intTextBox + "'/>";
  contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
}
//FUNCTION TO REMOVE TEXT BOX ELEMENT
function removeElement() {
  if (intTextBox != 0) {
    var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
    contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('strText' + intTextBox));
    intTextBox = intTextBox - 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Adding and Removing Text Boxes Dynamically</title>

</head>

<body>
  <p>Demo of Adding and Removing Text Box Dynamically using JavaScript</p>
  <p><a href="#" onclick="addElement()">Add</a> <a href="#" onclick="removeElement()">Remove</a></p>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today's solution is to use vanilla Javascript's [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Something like:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p class="dynamicClass">Dynamic stuff</p>');
document.querySelector('.dynamicClass').remove(); // to remove it
```

Or you could create the element first and do stuff with it (remove it etc) with [insertAdjacentElement(position, element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

```
const tempP = document.createElement('p');
tempP.textContent='hello';
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', tempP);
tempP.remove(); // to remove it
```